# What is the preferred way in mill to point to the directory where build.sc file is located?

Tags: scala, build-tools, mill

What is the preferred way in mill to point to the directory where `build.sc` file is located?

In the mill documentation `os.pwd` is used e.g. [here](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Tasks.html), but if it is possible to start/run mill from elsewhere, then `os.pwd` points to incorrect location.

```
import mill._, mill.modules.Jvm

def sourceRoot = T.sources { os.pwd / "src" }

def resourceRoot = T.sources { os.pwd / "resources" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root location of each defined module is defined in `def millSourcePath: os.Path`, and it's the preferred way to access the module path.

Example:

```scala
import mill._, mill.scalalib._

object mymodule extends JavaModule {
  def sources = T.sources(millSourcePath / "src")
}
```

```sh
$ mill show __.sources
No mill version specified.
You should provide a version via '.mill-version' file or --mill-version option.
Using mill version 0.9.9
Compiling /tmp/stackoverflow/build.sc
[1/1] show 
[1/1] show > [1/1] mymodule.sources 
[
    "ref:c984eca8:/tmp/stackoverflow/mymodule/src"
]
```

If you need to access the path of project itself, notice, that it's a `mill.define.Module` itself and you can access it via the variable `build`. The project directory is therefore accessible via `build.millSourcePath`.

Example:

```scala
import mill._, mill.scalalib._

val baseDir = build.millSourcePath

object mymodule extends JavaModule {
  def sources = T.sources {
    super.sources() ++ Seq(PathRef(baseDir / "src"))
  }
}
```

```sh
$ mill show __.sources
No mill version specified.
You should provide a version via '.mill-version' file or --mill-version option.
Using mill version 0.9.9
Compiling /tmp/stackoverflow/build.sc
[1/1] show 
[1/1] show > [2/2] mymodule.sources 
[
    "ref:c984eca8:/tmp/stackoverflow/mymodule/src",
    "ref:c984eca8:/tmp/stackoverflow/src"
]
```

Comment: Thank you! build.millSourcePath was exactly what I was looking for! It works but for some reason my Idea v2021.2.1 does not find it and wants to import mill.modules.Jvm.JarManifest.Default.build, which is def returning Manifest.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is using its Ammonite support to "understand" the `build.sc`. (Mill build scripts are also Ammonite scripts.) The exposed `build` object is Mill specific and therefore unknown to IJ.